# Having trouble with linked lists, program will not print the elements

Tags: c, linked-list

I am supposed to do an assignment in C programming language. It includes linked lists and reading user input from the console.

The user inputs numbers into the console, for example ( 1 3 5 7 0 ), which are added, one by one, to the beginning of the linked list. 0 marks the end of the transition. This is what the linked list should look like after the first part: 7 5 3 1

I need to code two different functions that will delete different elements of the linked list.

First function deletes all elements from the list that have the value that you input, and second function deletes the element on the position that the user inputs, if it exists.

At the end, you should print the list.

I've written the the first function correctly, and I am sure about it, with the second function (the one that deletes elements on a certain position) I had some trouble. I made a simple function that counts how many nodes are there in total, so if someone puts a number larger than the amount of nodes, a message would pop up. I also used that function to make a for loop and used it as a limit when searching for the element on a certain position, if that makes any sense. The program also won't print anything, I have no idea why.

```
    typedef struct Element Element;

    struct Element
    {
        int number;
        Element *next;
    };

    Element *addnewN(int number)
    {
       Element *newN = (Element*)malloc(sizeof(Element));

       newN->number = number;
       newN->next = NULL;

       return newN;
    }

    Element *add_on_beginning(Element *head, Element *newN)
    {
       newN->next = head;

       return head;
    }

    Element* delete_value(Element* head, int value)
    {
       Element *before = NULL;
       Element *temp = head;
       Element *newNhead = head;

       while(temp != NULL)
       {
          if(temp->number == value)
          {
            if(before == NULL)
            {
               newNhead = temp->next;
               free(temp);
               temp = newNhead;
            }
            else
            {
                before->next = temp->next;
                free(temp);
                temp = before->next;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            before = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }

     }
       return newNhead;
    }

    int counter(Element *head)
    {
       int count = 0;
       Element *temp = head;

       while(temp != NULL)
       {
         count++;
         temp = temp->next;
       }
       return count;
     }

    Element* delete_on_position(Element* head, int position)
    {
       int limit = counter(head);

       Element *temp = head;
       Element *newNhead = head;
       Element *before = NULL;

       if(position > limit)
       {
         printf("Error.\n");
       }

       for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
       {
          if(position == 0)
       {
          newNhead = temp->next;
          free(temp);
          temp = newNhead;
    }
    else if(position == i)
    {
        before->next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        temp = before->next;
    }
    else
    {
        before = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
return head;
}

void printElement(Element *element)
{
   printf("%d ", element->number);
}

void printList(Element *head)
{
   Element *temp = head;

   while(temp != NULL)
   {
      printElement(temp);
      temp = temp->next;
   }
}

void menu()
{
   printf("\t MENU \n");
   printf("1. Delete all elements from the list that have the value that 
   you input.\n");
   printf("2. Delete the element on the position, if it exists.\n");
   printf("3. Print the list. \n");
   printf("4. Exit \n");
}

int main()
{
    Element *head = NULL;

    int i = 0;
    int arr[1000];
    char temp;
    int x;
    int y;

    printf("Input the numbers you want: \n");

    while(temp != '\n')
    {
       scanf("%d%c", &arr[i], &temp);

       if(arr[i] == 0)
       {
          break;
       }

       head = add_on_beginning(head, addnewN(arr[i]));

       i++;
     }

     menu();

     while(1)
     {
        scanf("%d", &x);

        switch(x)
       {
          case 1:
          {
             scanf("%d", &y);
             head = delete_value(head, y);
             break;
          }
          case 2:
          {
             scanf("%d", &y);
             head = delete_on_position(head, y);
             break;
          }
          case 3:
          {
              printList(head);
              break;
          }
          case 4:
          {
              return 0;
          }
     }

  }

   return 0;

 }
```

What you are supposed to get would be for example:

Input: 2 4 5 8 5 0 (in one line), and in one line each:

```
2
2
1
5
3
```

Output: `2 8`

When debugged, the code does not show any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_on_beginning` is not returning the correct value. It should return the node that was added, since it's the new head of the list. Nothing else will work correctly because of that, because `head` will always be `NULL`.

```
Element *add_on_beginning(Element *head, Element *newN)
{
   newN->next = head;

   return newN;
}
```